# How to set up ArgoCD notification with Teams

Tags: argocd, argocd-notification

I am trying to use ArgoCD notification to my Teams channel, but it isn't sending notification. So, I followed documentation here

1. I created an Incoming Webhook in teams and get URL
2. I set it to argocd-notification secrets:

   ```yaml
   apiVersion: v1  
   kind: Secret
   metadata:   
     name: argocd-notifications-secret
   stringData:
     channel-teams-url: mywebhookurl
   type: Opaque
   ```
3. Then I set up config map:

   ```yaml
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: ConfigMap
   metadata:
     name: argocd-notifications-cm
   data:
     context: |
       argocdUrl: https://20.204.207.96
     trigger.on-health-degraded: |
       when: app.status.health.status == 'Degraded'
       send: [app-on-health-degraded]
     trigger.on-deployed: |
       when: app.status.operationState.phase in ['Succeeded'] and app.status.health.status == 'Healthy'
       oncePer: app.status.sync.revision
       send: [app-sync-succeeded]
     service.teams: |
       recipientUrls: 
         ArgoCD: $channel-teams-url
     template.app-on-health-degraded: |
       email:
         subject: Application {{.app.metadata.name}} has degraded.
       message: |
         Application {{.app.metadata.name}} has degraded.
         Application details: {{.context.argocdUrl}}/applications/{{.app.metadata.name}}.
       teams:
         facts: |
           [{
             "name": "Sync Status",
             "value": "{{.app.status.sync.status}}"
           },
           {
             "name": "Repository",
             "value": "{{.app.spec.source.repoURL}}"
           }
           {{range $index, $c := .app.status.conditions}}
             {{if not $index}},{{end}}
             {{if $index}},{{end}}
             {
               "name": "{{$c.type}}",
               "value": "{{$c.message}}",
             }
           {{end}}
           ]
         potentialAction: |
           [{
             "@type":"OpenUri",
             "name":"Open Application",
             "targets":[{
               "os":"default",
               "uri":"{{.context.argocdUrl}}/applications/{{.app.metadata.name}}"
             }]
           },
           {
             "@type":"OpenUri",
             "name":"Open Repository",
             "targets":[{
               "os":"default",
               "uri":"{{.app.spec.source.repoURL | call .repo.RepoURLToHTTPS}}"
             }]
           }]
         title: Application {{.app.metadata.name}} has degraded.

     template.app-sync-succeeded: |
       teams:
         facts: |
           [{
             "name": "Sync Status",
             "value": "{{.app.status.sync.status}}"
           },
           {
             "name": "Repository",
             "value": "{{.app.spec.source.repoURL}}"
           },
           {
             "name": "Revision",
             "value": "{{.app.status.sync.revision}}"
           }
           {{range $index, $c := .app.status.conditions}}
             {{if not $index}},{{end}}
             {{if $index}},{{end}}
             {
               "name": "{{$c.type}}",
               "value": "{{$c.message}}",
             }
           {{end}}
           ]
         potentialAction: |-
           [{
             "@type":"OpenUri",
             "name":"Operation Application",
             "targets":[{
               "os":"default",
               "uri":"{{.context.argocdUrl}}/applications/{{.app.metadata.name}}"
             }]
           },
           {
             "@type":"OpenUri",
             "name":"Open Repository",
             "targets":[{
               "os":"default",
               "uri":"{{.app.spec.source.repoURL | call .repo.RepoURLToHTTPS}}"
             }]
           }]
         title: New version of an application {{.app.metadata.name}} is up and running.
   ```
4. Then I subscribe it from application:

   ```yaml
   apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
   kind: Application
   metadata:
     name: dreambook-argo-application
     namespace: argocd
     annotations:
       notifications.argoproj.io/subscribe.on-sync-running.teams: ArgoCD
       notifications.argoproj.io/subscribe.on-deployed.teams: ArgoCD
       notifications.argoproj.io/subscribe.on-health-degraded: ArgoCD
   spec:
     project: default
     source:
       repoURL: myrepo url
       targetRevision: HEAD
       path: dev/deployment
     destination:
       server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
       namespace: myns
     syncPolicy:
       automated:
         prune: true
         selfHeal: true
       syncOptions:
         - Validate=false
         - Prune=true
         - SelfHeal=true
   ```

So, my channel in Teams is ArgoCD:

[image: my channel]

So, after CI/CD I am not getting any notification. Does anyone have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you applied your secret with a namespace flag or not, but make sure it's in the same namespace as the other resources.

If that is not the issue I'll just assume that the notification controller is not able to send the message due to missing text. The [official notification](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/notifications_catalog/install.yaml) template has this missing for the teams templates.

You can find that out by getting the logs of the argocd notification-controller. Notification controller should be an already running pod in your respective namespace (from what it seems to me, probably at argocd).

```
kubectl logs get pods argocd-notifications-controller-xxx -n argocd -f
```

Just keep watching the pod logs and sync the application in argocd, you should get some logs that indicate that a message was attempted to send.
In case it somewhere says

> Failed to notify recipient {teams myChannelName} defined in resource myApplication: teams webhook post error: Summary or Text is required.

Then the solution is to add another text field in the template. A working template of mine looks like this:

```
template.app-sync-succeeded: |
  teams:
    facts: |
      [{
        "name": "Sync Status",
        "value": "{{.app.status.sync.status}}"
      },
      {
        "name": "Synced at",
        "value": "{{.app.status.operationState.finishedAt}}"
      },
      {
        "name": "Repository",
        "value": "{{.app.spec.source.repoURL}}"
      }
      {{range $index, $c := .app.status.conditions}}
        {{if not $index}},{{end}}
        {{if $index}},{{end}}
        {
          "name": "{{$c.type}}",
          "value": "{{$c.message}}"
        }
      {{end}}
      ]
    potentialAction: |-
      [{
        "@type":"OpenUri",
        "name":"Operation Details",
        "targets":[{
          "os":"default",
          "uri":"{{.context.argocdUrl}}/applications/{{.app.metadata.name}}?operation=true"
        }]
      },
      {
        "@type":"OpenUri",
        "name":"Open Repository",
        "targets":[{
          "os":"default",
          "uri":"{{.app.spec.source.repoURL | call .repo.RepoURLToHTTPS}}"
        }]
      }]
    themeColor: '#000080'
    title: Application {{.app.metadata.name}} has been successfully synced
    text: Application {{.app.metadata.name}} has been successfully synced at {{.app.status.operationState.finishedAt}}.
```